# trigger.io error device-ios.app/Forge malformed object

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am trying to run [this weather tutorial](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.2/tutorials/weather/tutorial-1.html) app on an actual iPhone (I've got it working on the emulator so far).

> [ERROR] Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: codesign_allocate:
>   object:
>   /Users/cdplMBP17/Documents/AppDev/trigger/development/ios/device-ios.app/Forge
>   malformed object (unknown load command 43)
>   /Users/cdplMBP17/Documents/AppDev/trigger/development/ios/device-ios.app:
>   object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you have an older version of Xcode or if the Xcode command line tools have got into a bad state.

I recommend trying the following

1) Make sure the latest Xcode is installed from the app store.

2) Make sure the command line tools are installed and Xcode is aware they are installed. To install the command line tools, open the Xcode preferences and go to Downloads, there should be an install button next to Command Line Tools (see the image below).

[image: Xcode prefs]

If this doesn't help then your version of OS X and the full log output from the failed run on a device would be helpful.